# Generating active character with char code "0C with expl3 gives \ERROR instead?

Tags: tex-core, expl3

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\typeout{error: \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \string \char_generate:nn {"0C} {13}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
error:\ERROR
```

Compile with `latex` or `pdflatex`.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I get `error:\ERROR` in either case.

Comment: @egreg Probably a mistake.

Comment: Partial progress update: looks like this is somewhat intentional (source3.pdf page 863 search for ^^L)

Comment: `^^L` is not `\outer` in LaTeX, but it is in plain TeX and the code is meant to be engine independent. Thus the precaution. Possibly something to think about.

Comment: I think it should be possible to generate active characters even if they're outer, but that would need some rewriting of the current code. The current code looks like there's another problem that if one of the active character is defined to be something like `\fi` it would cause trouble

Comment: I'm wondering why you expect to _know_ what will happen if you generate an active char for which you've not provided a defintion

Comment: @JosephWright \string should handle it regardless? Char_generate is documented to expand to the active character in exactly 2 expansion steps anyway

Comment: @user202729 I just re-checked the code: from memory, the plan was that active `^^L` simply can't be handled safely in a general sense, due to plain TeX making it `\outer`, so we had to take a path that would at least work. I guess this should be a documented limitation.

Comment: @JosephWright It can be handled safely but requires modification of the current code. For example by storing ^^L as the first token in the token list instead of last, then expand the token list, put a `\noexpand` before it, then apply one expansion level on the `\noexpand`, then you can grab the active character as a token or skip through it in the ⟨false code⟩ text.

Comment: @user202729 A patch or pull request most welcome;)

Comment: @JosephWright Proof of concept: https://gist.github.com/user202729/b0bec0373aeffafbfb5b401e1cc3e938 (does not follow expl3 naming convention though). Maybe someday I clean up the thing will make a pull request...? (token manipulation approach would save a few tokens though and potentially faster than subtracting from 13)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for `\char_generate:nn` with 8-bit engines uses an approach with a set of pre-stored tokens to 'generate' the results. With the code as set up to end-2022, this did not allow `\outer` actives to be created. As `^^L` is `\outer` in plain TeX, `expl3` deliberately filtered this case out and replaced by `\ERROR` to avoid an uncontrolled error.

As discussed in comments, by reversing the stored tokens such that catode-13 is first, it is possible to avoid an uncontrolled situation by applying `\noexpand` during generation of actives. Thus `expl3` releases from 2023 onward do not have this limitation.

Comment: Relevant commit: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/d1001f2738cf1423e50486707def96166024361d